# Can localStorage be accessed by the user in a windows store app?

Tags: javascript, php, windows, html, windows-store-apps

I have a html5 app online that I am converting to a windows 8 store application.

It has a saving feature where an encrypted string is put into localStorage and deycrpted server side so that the user will have difficulty in cheating to get achievements.

However, I can't use the server in a windows store app because of the AJAX restrictions. So if I saved the savegame as plain text, would the localStorage variable be accessible by the user?

Comment: `However, I can't use the server in a windows store app because of the AJAX restrictions` wrong; Windows Store apps are allowed to connect to the internet.

Comment: Any data stored on a user's device is accessible by said user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @SLacks mentioned, anything stored on the file system is available to the user. You can, however, encrypt the data before it goes to the file system. If you write yourself a local storage controller to handler reading and writing, then you can access the filesystem through this boundary such that the rest of your code will not know that the files are encrypted.